# Creation matrices with a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

Hi i would like to create 15 Matrices with different columns,i tried this code

```
for(i in 1:15){Di=matrix(0,i,1000)}
for(i in 1:15){for(k in 1:i){for(j in 1:1000){Di[k,j]=runif(1,-1,1)}}}
```

but `Di` did not create D1,D2 vs. matrices for me `Di` stayed as one whole matrix, how can I create 15 different matrices?

Comment: Thank you but now l[2] supposed to have 2 columns,how can i do that i want l[1] with 1 column 1000 row,l[2] with 2 column 1000 row and so goes on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `list` for this:

```
 l <- vector(mode="list", length=15)

 for (i in seq(along=l)) {
   l[[i]] <- matrix(runif(i*1000, -1, 1), nrow=1000, ncol=i)
 }
```

Comment: Thank you but now l[2] supposed to have 2 columns,how can i do that i want l[1] with 1 column 1000 row,l[2] with 2 column 1000 row and so goes on

Comment: sorry but one last question how can i reach to for example l[4] row 500 column 3?

Comment: @user3528850 `matrix(runif((i-1)*500, -1, 1), nrow=500, ncol=(i-1))`?

Comment: i meant after creation i want just directly to read the value at l[a] row b and c, i mean like l[a,b,c] or something like that i just want to get the value,sorry if this is a dummy question

Comment: i created matrices using your code and now i just want to read the value l[a] column a and row b

Comment: @user3528850: `l[[a]][b, c]` (a==matrix number, b==row, c==column). That are very basic questions. I would suggest to read http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf